# How to differentiate $y = C(x)e^{-\int p(x) dx }$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In a book following equation:

$$
y = C(x)e^{-\int p(x) dx }
$$

is differentiated into:

$$
y' = C'(x)e^{-\int p(x) dx } + C(x)\left( -p(x) \cdot e^{-\int p(x) dx }\right )
$$

but there are no intermediate steps shown. How to obtain this result? It's problematic especially because of the "$\int p(x)\ldots$" integral.

Comment: I guess this is a problem with the notation. Would you know how to do it if the integral were $\int_a^x\!dx'\,p(x')$?

Comment: @VolkerAmnu  Note that $\int{p(x)dx}$ gives the anti derivative of $p(x)$ And when you differentiate the anti derivative of a function again you get the same function which in this case is $p(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the product rule. $(uv)'=u'v+v'u$ Here $u=C(x)$ and $v=e^{-\int{p(x)dx}}$. The anti derivative of $e^{-\int{p(x)dx}}$ as pointed out above is $-p(x)e^{-\int{p(x)dx}}$